# BLE112 thermometer demo, source code of the BLE112 firmware

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

We (will) have a BLE112, and we want to program it with a CC Debuger connected to the PC.
http://www.bluegiga.com/BLE112_Bluetooth_Smart_module
http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/swru197f/swru197f.pdf

We want to test the thermometer demo available at:
https://techforum.bluegiga.com/ble112?downloads#3.1 -> Bluetooth Smart: v.1.0.3 Software Development Kit 
-> ble-1.0.3-43.zip -> src/thermometer-demo

this code "thermometer-demo" is the client PC application that connects to the BLE112 and asks to read the temperature.

but, where is the firmware source code for the BLE112 thermometer-demo?

Answer (score 0):

There should be a .hex file in that folder. This is what you want to specify for the path in the BG Update Utility. If it hasn't been compiled yet, there won't be a .hex file.

In that case, just point the BG Update Utility to the project.xml file (could also be project.bgproj) and it will compile on the fly for you.

Also, if you are looking at their /src directory, that's just for their iOS examples. To get to firmware, look at /examples in their SDK.